# How to calculate MySQL GROUP BY boundaries with unix timestamps

Tags: mysql

For performance reasons I need to create a materialized view of data totaled by day. The timestamp is stored as UNIX timestamp.

To allow updating (REPLACEing) into the materialized view's table I'd like it to have a timestamp, again in UNIX timestamp format, matching the beginning (or end) of the day. That timestamp will become part of the table's key. 
Whenever base table data changes I could then update the view's table for that particular day only (again for performance).

My current aggregation statement looks like this:

```
REPLACE INTO aggregate_data (channel_id, type, timestamp, value)
SELECT channel_id, 'day' AS type, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp, SUM(value) AS value
FROM data
GROUP BY channel_id, YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp/1000)), DAYOFYEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp/1000));
```

How can I make MAX(timestamp) match the day's boundary (24:00) instead of the last aggregated data's timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question right. Are you looking for something like this?

```
REPLACE INTO aggregate_data (channel_id, type, timestamp, value)
SELECT channel_id, 'day' AS type, 

UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(timestamp)), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59'))
AS timestamp, 

SUM(value) AS value
FROM data
GROUP BY channel_id, YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp/1000)), DAYOFYEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp/1000));
```

Comment: Thank you- the to-and-from UNIX timestamp conversion brought me on the right path

Answer (score 0):

No need to use MAX, you can just use FROM_UNIXTIME() to convert an unix timestamp to a specific Day.

```
REPLACE INTO aggregate_data (channel_id, type, timestamp, value)
SELECT channel_id, 
       'day' AS type, 
       FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AS timestamp, 
       SUM(value) AS value
FROM data
GROUP BY channel_id, FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00');
```

Check also this code on [SQLFiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cbadd/18)

Comment: don't think this works as timestamp is grouped- so which one is taken?